# How much player XP can be earned through evolving 3-stage evolution Pokémon to their third stage?

Tags: pokemon-go

For power leveling your player with common 3-Stage evolution Pokémon:

1. Weedle
2. Caterpie
3. Pidgey

The first evolution costs 12 candies and gives 1000 player XP, which is 83 exp/candy.

How much player XP is granted for evolving to their final form for 50 candy?

Comment: Evolving Pokémon is similar to catching them. You get an extra 500 XP for registering a new Pokémon to the Pokedex, either through capture, or through evolution. So the *actual* amount of XP granted fro an evolution is 500 XP, regardless of the Pokémon, which does not change regardless of the evolution "stage".

Answer (score 7):

You gain 500 XP for evolving a Pokemon. This is a flat reward which has no bearing on whether the Pokemon is evolving into it's 2nd or 3rd stage.

You also gain 500XP for registering a new Pokemon. When you evolve a Pokemon, if that new Pokemon doesn't already exist in your Pokedex it will be added, and you will receive the 500XP for this action as well. This will net you a total of 1000XP (evolution + new registered Pokemon).