# What are the most effective evolutions regarding EP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I wanted to know if anybody has calculated what the best Evolutions are regarding EP per Candy (Rarity doesn't count here).

For example: Is it wiser to evolve several Pidgeys to Pidgeotto or to evolve Pidgeotto to Pidgeot one time? Which Pokémon is the best example here for as many EP as possible?

Comment: According to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273215/how-much-player-xp-can-be-earned-through-evolving-3-stage-evolution-pok%c3%a9mon-to-t every evolution gives 500 Exp, so the answer to this would just be the easiest Pokémon to evolve. I have no idea what that is as I haven't played the game.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Thats true. I forgot that the 1000EP only comes for new Pokemon. And so I thought there is a difference. So the answer is probably Weedle and Caterpie.

Comment: Yes, every evolution gives 500 xp (Not sure about Magikarp -> Gyarados, though). It's wise to evolve several Pidgeys instead of going for a Pidgeot, which costs 4 times the materials with no extra xp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Pokémon you don't have, is worth more than repeated evolutions. So trying to complete your pokédex is always a good idea for gathering experience.

After that, you should primarily be concerned with the following three evolutions:

Weedle > Kakuna
Caterpie > Metapod
Pidgey > Pidgeotto

These evolutions cost only 12 candy, while all others cost at least 25. Since all evolutions reward you 500 xp, these three give the biggest bang for your buck.

And if you can, use Lucky Egg to double all xp you get from these evolutions!